# WiFi card not compatible with router?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I've got a new `ADB EA4201N-G` router that is used by the way also for cable TV. All PC are connected to this router via WiFi without problems except one - `Asus EE PC Flare series`.

I have installed two OS on this laptop - Ubuntu Linux and Windows 8. Both of these systems can't connect to acces point.

Linux writes messages `Authentication` and then `Obtaining IP ...'and then it not connects to WiFi.

If I run Windows on this PC it just not connects to access point. This netbook connects to others access points without problems. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you set up a MAC filter on your WiFi router?

Comment: no, I did'n set mac filter